# Cakephp join table syntax

Tags: mysql, cakephp, join

How to set an association between Table A and B where if a record exists in table B then nothing at all will be shown( like a inner join reverse).
Can this be done using Exists or not Exists? What will be the cakephp syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `not exists`:

```
select * from tableA a
inner join tableB b on b.id not exists (select id from tableA where id <> b.id)
```